# angularjs services with a returning test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to create a serice in order to check if the user is connected before doing anything.

the service is:

```
app.service('generalService', function ($rootScope, ngDialog, Data, $location) {
    this.checklogin = function(id) {
        Data.get('checklogin').then(function (data) { 
            // no logged user, redirect to /login
            if (!data) {
                $location.path("/login");
            }
            return data;
        });
    }
});
```

And that's how I try to use it in a controller:

```
app.controller('childrenCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $filter, Data, $location, $routeParams, generalService, childstatus) {
  $scope.changepresence = function(child) { 
    generalService.checklogin($scope.child).then(function(res) {
      if(data) {
        // effective code here
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I got the following error: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: checklogin is already returning the data not a promise.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment. The method checklogin is already returning the data and not a promise. So you need to change it for this if you want to keep using the promise in the other method.

```
app.service('generalService', function ($rootScope, ngDialog, Data, $location) {
    this.checklogin = function(id) {
        return Data.get('checklogin');

    }
});

app.controller('childrenCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $filter, Data, $location, $routeParams, generalService, childstatus) {
  $scope.changepresence = function(child) { 
    generalService.checklogin($scope.child).then(function(data) {
      if(!data) {
        // effective code here
         $location.path("/login");
      }
      //process the data.
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it means that I need to make the redirection: $location.path("/login") in each of the places I want to test ? Isn't a way to make this action once in the service ?